# Ruby: What's the difference between STDIN.gets() and gets.chomp()?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between `STDIN.gets()` and `gets.chomp()` in Ruby? Aren't they both retrieving raw input from the user?

side question: If I want to convert their input into an integer, do I do

```
myNumb = Integer(STDIN.gets())
```

and

```
myNumb = Integer(gets.chomp())
```

Comment: Why are you comparing one with chomp and another without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to do what you describe here is `Integer(gets)`, since `Integer()` ignores the trailing newline, so `chomp` is unnecessary. There's also no need explicitly specify `STDIN` as the receiver, as that's what [Kernel#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) will do if there are no arguments to the script.

Answer (score 20):

`gets` is actually [Kernel#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). It reads from files passed as arguments or, if no arguments are present, reads from standard input. If you want to read only from standard input, then you should be more explicit about it.

```
STDIN.gets
$stdin.gets
```

As for the conversion, I normally use [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i). It handles newlines just fine.

Comment: But still, Integer( string ) has undeniable advantages over string.to_i.

Comment: `to_i` and `Integer()` are very different. Personally I rather deal with an exception than getting a random 0.

Comment: There are pros and cons for each method. :)

Answer (score 5):

because
if there is stuff in ARGV, the default gets method tries to treat the first one as a file and read
from that. To read from the user's input (i.e., stdin) in such a situation, you have to use
it STDIN.gets explicitly.