# gets is not called within a Ruby method

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I want to display the value of an instance variable to the user, then ask what the value should be using `gets.chomp`. Because I'll be doing this for several variables, I want to check the value with a method. My difficulty is that when I call `gets` in a method, the program runs without asking for user input.

Here is the relevant part of code:

```
class TagPodcast

  # ... Code to pull ID3v2 tags from MP3 file

  def inspect_tags
    puts "Title: " + @title
    set_tag(self.title)
  end

  def set_tag(tag)
    new_value = gets.chomp
    tag = new_value unless new_value == ""
  end

end

TagPodcast.new("myfile.mp3").inspect_tags
```

When I run the program, it prints `Title: My Title Here` but then exits without asking for input. What do I need to do to call `gets`?

Comment: This is unrelated to your `gets` problem, but as it stands right now `set_tag` will not set anything; I suspect you want to do something like `self.tag = tag` or `@tag = tag` at the end (unless this is pseudocode).

Comment: Have you tried STDIN.gets.chomp or $stdin.gets.chomp to ensure you are getting input from the expected source?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12041600/1286639

Comment: @GoZoner: Using `STDIN.gets.chomp` works as expected. If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: If you use `ARGV` in your script it will interfere with `gets`. You can avoid this by using `STDIN.gets`.

Comment: @JimStewart Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm calling `set_tag with a symbol, thus: `set_tag(:@title)` And now I'm setting that value with this line `self.instance_variable_set(tag, new_value) unless new_value == ""` Does that look better?

Comment: @effbott: That was the problem. I was using `ARGV` to get the filename.

Comment: @LincolnMullen, you don't ever need to use `instance_variable_set` to set an instance variable of the current class (really, you should never use `instance_variable_set` under any circumstances, but it's sometimes handy to spike out tests until you can properly inject dependencies).  Use `self.tag = whatever`, and define a setter (either via `attr_writer/attr_accessor`, or just define it explicitly as `def tag=(val); @tag = val; end`, or just set `@tag = val`, which within the class is identical to `instance_variable_set(:tag, val)`.  I prefer to use accessors, even if private.

Comment: @LincolnMullen, you don't ever need to use `instance_variable_set` to set an instance variable of the current class (really, you should never use `instance_variable_set` under any circumstances, but it's sometimes handy to spike out tests until you can properly inject dependencies).  Use `self.tag = whatever`, and define a setter (either via `attr_writer/attr_accessor`, or just define it explicitly as `def tag=(val); @tag = val; end`, or just set `@tag = val`, which within the class is identical to `instance_variable_set(:tag, val)`.  I prefer to use accessors, even if private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are getting input from standard input with:

```
STDIN.gets.chomp
```

or

```
$stdin.gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 2):

This (sligtly modified) program asks me for input as expected (just added accessor and constructor):

```
class TagPodcast
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
  end

  def inspect_tags
    puts "Title: " + @title
    set_tag(self.title)
  end

  def set_tag(tag)
    new_value = gets.chomp
    tag = new_value unless new_value == ""
  end
end

tp = TagPodcast.new("myfile.mp3")
tp.title = 'Dummy Title'

tp.inspect_tags
```

Your code has a different problem, though. Variables are passed into methods by value, not by reference, so this code will not behave as expected:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :variable

  def set_var(var)
    var = 'new value'
  end

  def bar
    self.variable = 'old value'
    set_var(self.variable)

    puts "@variable is now #{self.variable}"
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

this will print `@variable is now old value`. I can think of two ways around this. Either set the instance variable outside the method like so:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :variable

  def do_stuff
    'new value'
  end

  def bar
    self.variable = 'old value'
    self.variable = do_stuff

    puts "@variable is now #{self.variable}"
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

or use Ruby's powerful metaprogramming features and leverage `instance_variable_set` to dynamically set an instance variable by passing its name as a symbol:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :variable

  def set_var(var)
    instance_variable_set var, 'new value'
  end

  def bar
    self.variable = 'old value'
    set_var(:@variable)

    puts "@variable is now #{self.variable}"
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

As for your original question, we need to know more about the execution context. Probably STDIN is not what you expect it to be at execution time.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using `instance_variable_set` works like a charm. As @GoZoner and @Effbot pointed out in comments above, the problem was using `ARGV` which changed STDIN.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the update, good to know about this issue! Might happen to all of us at some point…