# Ruby gets.chomp and $stdin.gets.chomp difference

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

```
filename = ARGV.first 

txt = open(filename)

puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"
print txt.read

print "Type the filename again: "
file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Here is my question if I change it to `gets.chomp` it doesn't work **why ?**

```
txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read
```

What's the difference between `gets.chomp` and `$stdin.chomp`

Comment: Have you seen this [SO-Question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041492/ruby-whats-the-difference-between-stdin-gets-and-gets-chomp) and  [SO-Question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523536/whats-the-difference-between-gets-chomp-vs-stdin-gets-chomp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523536/whats-the-difference-between-gets-chomp-vs-stdin-gets-chomp has the answer with the precise difference.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Kernel#gets docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) (emphasis mine):

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line **from the list of files in ARGV** (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

In your case, ARGV is non-empty, so `Kernel#gets` applies to it: